# How to write data to a csv file in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I can't seem to find the correct syntax for this. My code loads a file "sensordata.mat" that is called "temps", and uses this for results. At the end of the code it should write my data to a csv file. I tried the following:

```
writetable('sensordata.csv','temps')
```

This only gives me an error stating:`Undefined function 'write' for input arguments of type 'char'.`

Does anyone know the solution for this? Thank you for your expertise.

Comment: Please try and search for questions that are related to yours before asking.  It minimizes clutter.  The above link I found in 3 minutes using the search bar here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

CSV support is built into MATLAB:

```
csvwrite('sensordata.csv', temps);
```